# How to send token from server to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth

I have express app, running on port 8000, I also have react on port 3000.
I am trying to implement google oauth.

This is what I did.

I try to send get request to my api endpoint,
then my express server redirect user to google Sign in.

[image]

And then, how can I send token from server to client from `get` request?
Here's my express code.
I try to send cookies directly from the server,
but I don't know why the cookies is not available on port 3000 which is my react app.
Is there any neat way to send jwt to client?

```
router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"],
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    session: false,
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    const payload = {
      id: req.user.id,
    };

    jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresIn: tokenLife }, (err, token) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('error', err)
      }
      const jwt = `Bearer ${token}`;
      console.log('ini token', token)

      const htmlWithEmbeddedJWT = `
    <html>
      <script>
        // Save JWT to cookie
        // document.cookie = 'token=${jwt};'
        document.cookie = 'token=${jwt}; SameSite=None; Secure'
        // Redirect browser to root of application
        window.open('http://localhost:3000/login', '_self')
      </script>
    </html>
    `;

      res.send(htmlWithEmbeddedJWT);
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not available because you have responded to the google call and then redirected the page on a client to the localhost apparently cookies will not be available.

The common way to handle auth in such cases is to define a success redirect that will expect to receive somekind of a token in query params.

Comment: So, I should send query params in my react app? Thank you for answering btw

Comment: You should send the query params from the server, when you are doing a redirect on success.